# Material doesn't move with object, it remains static

Tags: materials

I'm having issues with my material appearing static throughout the transform of the object. The object will move but the material seems to stay static. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-jWT1q_Fx4 This link is similar to what I am seeing if you look at the clothes of the character in the youtube video.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a texture coordinate setup using the UV?

Comment: Post an image of the node setup

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing how you set up the material. But the error is definitely that you are using the wrong coordinates for mapping. To learn about texture coordinates I suggest that you watch the following video: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=263)

Comment: @Motcho I added an image of the node setup I'm using

Comment: @susu I added an image of the node setup, thanks for explaining texture coordinates I'll take a look at that

Comment: @EricXue I don't think I have a texture coordinate setup because when I click on the UV/Image Editor view I'm not able to see anything